# Create a hash function that maps each natural number to one of 9 buckets

Tags: python

Create a hash function that maps each natural number to one of 9 buckets {1, 2, ..., 9}. At the same time, add up all of the digits in numbers greater than 9 until only one digit remains (e.g., 128 becomes 11, which becomes 2)
Fill each bucket for numbers 1:1000

currently have:

```
x = 0
buckets = {}
buckets = {1:0, 2:0, 3:0, 4:0, 5:0, 6:0, 7:0, 8:0, 9:0}
while x in range(11):
    x += 1
    j = x
    while j > 9:
        x = sum(int(digit) for digit in str(x))
    if x in buckets:
        buckets[x] += 1
for keys,values in buckets.items():
    print(keys)
    print(values)
```

Thank you

Comment: Not sure why there are minus ratings but I actually almost have this figured out...

Comment: `while j > 9:` is an infinite loop if the condition is true the first time, because nothing inside the loop changes `j`.  And the outer `while` loop would be infinite if the inner one wasn't, because you're never allowing `x` to exceed 9.  Looks like the last four `x`s should have been `j`s.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I changed the last four x s to j s as shown in the below answer. I have mostly what I want, but can't figure out why it times out after 20 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 1
buckets = {}
buckets = {'1':0, '2':0, '3':0, '4':0, '5':0, '6':0, '7':0, '8':0, '9':0}
while x < 20:
    j = x
    while j > 9:
        j = sum(int(digit) for digit in str(x))
    if str(j) in buckets:
        buckets[str(j)] += 1
    x += 1
print(buckets)
```

Comment: The only issue I have is that it times out at 20 and I don't know why...

Comment: The line `j = sum(int(digit) for digit in str(x))` still has the `x` at the end. Should be `j = sum(int(digit) for digit in str(j))`. The infinite loop occurs at `19` because that's the first time the `while j > 9` loop repeats, and it stays stuck on `1 + 9 = 10` since it's `str(x)` instead of `str(j)` on that line. (As per @jasonharper's comment.)

Comment: Also, you don't need `if str(j) in buckets` since you've initialised 1-9 to `0` in `buckets`. Btw, that could be done as a dictionary comprehension: `buckets = {n: 0 for n in range(1, 10)}`

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers